# Скрыть li если отображается меньше 2 в ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как скрыть li элементы внутри ul если отображается меньше двух элементов
Например скрыть li, если отображается вот так

```
<ul> 
<li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно проще... Если именно скрыть

```css
ul:not(:nth-child(2)){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>text2</li>
  <li>text2</li>
</ul>
```

Но я бы рекомендовал. Не выводить, на стороне сервера, если в цикле менше 1-го элемента это будет более правильнее.

Answer (score 1):

Вставлю и я свои "три копейки"...
На мой взгляд, [решение BlackStar1991](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561782/182750) хоть и работает, но имеет один серьёзный недостаток - CSS стиль придётся повторить для 3х, 4х и более элементов примерно так:

```css
ul:not(:nth-child(2)),
ul:not(:nth-child(3)),
ul:not(:nth-child(4)), ... {
  display: none;
}
```

[Решение Алексея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561781/182750) лишено такого недостатка, но требует использование JavaScript.

Предлагаю использовать только CSS так:

```css
ul li:only-child {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text 1.1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>text 2.1</li>
  <li>text 2.2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>text 3.1</li>
  <li>text 3.2</li>
  <li>text 3.3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>text 4.1</li>
  <li>text 4.2</li>
  <li>text 4.3</li>
  <li>text 4.4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if ($('ul li').length < 2) { 
  $('ul li').hide();
}
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> 
<li>text</li>
</ul>
```